# Python polling MSSQL at set interval

Tags: python, timer, pymssql

I have a need to poll a MSSQL database to watch the status of a running job.  I want to run a status check every X seconds to see if the status=done. I am trying to use the threading module. I have tested the threading module with some simple print statements and it seems to work, but when I try inside my pymssql script it does not.

```
def watcher_query(cursor):
    print 'Watching'
    return cursor.execute(""" select *
                              from some_table' """)
def is_it_done(row):
    if row['status'] == 'done':
        return row['the_id'], True
    else:
        return row['the_id'], False

def d(cur):
    watcher_query(cur)
    for row in cur:
        return is_it_done(row)[1]
    threading.Timer(100, d).start()

def job_watch(server):
    with pymssql.connect(server_info) as conn:
        with conn.cursor(as_dict=True) as cur:
            is_done = false
            while is_done:
                is_done = d(cur)
```

No matter what I set the `threading.Timer` to I see the 'Watching' statement print constantly. Is there a better way to set the polling timer perhaps?

I have also tried to use Twisted to set up a basic function which makes a function call every X sec until some condition is met. I haven't tried it with MSSQL yet though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your code is written it doesn't seems to be in a working order:

1. It doesn't compile because of `is_done = false`,
2. If fixed to `is_done = False`, it skips the loop straight away,
3. Even if the loop is fixed in some reasonable way you never get to call `threading.Timer(100, d).start()` and don't examine any other rows as you return from `d` straight away after examining the first row using `return is_it_done(row)[1]`

It doesn't matter what the actual timed worker method does, prints to console or checks the database, should work just the same with the same timer.

What about something like this:

```
import threading


def is_it_done():
    # get some dummy predictable results
    if not hasattr(is_it_done, 'results'):
        is_it_done.results = iter([False] * 3)
    return next(is_it_done.results, True)


def job_watch():
    is_done = False

    def d():
        is_done = is_it_done()
        print('is_done: {}'.format(is_done))
        timer = threading.Timer(3, d).start()

    d()


job_watch()
```